# Printing barcode labels from PHP

Tags: php, css, printing

I'm currently using Jasper Report writer to design barcode labels and the Simit Group's jasperPHP class to produce a PDF file which is then sent to a Zebra termal printer. The jasperPHP class  leans heavily on Fpdf.

Unfortunately the barcode output on the Zebra printer is so narrow it cannot be read by our barcode scanner.

I'm thinking that we should consider a new strategy for label printing (4 inch by 5 inch). They  need to be compliant with the IATA 606 cargo label standard.  Does anyone have any advice on a better way to achieve this in PHP, CSS or other option ?

Comment: Well, a simple Google brings up several PHP libraries that may work for you. Such as [this](https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator)

Comment: Thanks, we are going to give that a try